# VB.NET Using recursion with 9 instances of a class, how to check what instance i'm on?

Tags: vb.net

**This is related to a *Think-A-Dot* college project.**

I have a list of objects of type Flipper as so:

```
flipper1, flipper2, flipper3... flipper8
```

My thought was to do a recursive function to iterate through each flipper and process each one individually instead of dealing with many if-statements; I figure going with something such as a recursive function should do the job?

As of right now I have the function:

```
Public Function Solve(ByRef flipper As Flipper) As Flipper


End Function
```

Should I use an if-statement in the function to check what flipper is being worked on at the moment and to ensure that the recursion exits when flipper9 is complete? How do I go about checking what object is being worked on, is there a way to verify the name of the object being passed in to keep track?

Comment: Perhaps an array of `Flipper`s would make it easier? Pass the array and index in the recursion.

Comment: Hmmm :) thats an idea, i will try that out! thank you

Comment: In addition to @LarsTech answer, familarize yourself with the Visual Studio debugger, the Call Stack, Immediate, Threads, Modules & etc windows. They are your best friends:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this statement:

> iterate through each flipper and process each one individually

makes it sound like you don't need to recurse anything, but you replace these variables with a list of variables.

```
Private flippers As New List(Of Flipper)
```

then you add your flipper objects to them (example):

```
flippers.Add(New Flipper())
```

then just iterate the collection:

```
For Each flip As Flipper In flippers

Next
```

Comment: "makes it sound like you don't need to recurse anything, but you replace these variables with a list of variables." i think your right, i was thinking this right before you posted the answer LarsTech.  Thank you!